# Calculate the mean on a Groupby Object in Pandas after applying .nsmallest(2)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame, which holds the performance results for many athletes. Now I want to group the data by 'BIB# and 'COURSE', so I write:

```
grupper = df.groupby(['BIB#', 'COURSE'])
```

Next, I want to find the two best runs (column = 'FINISH) for each 'BIB' and 'COURSE', so I write:

```
x = grupper.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(2, 'FINISH'))
```

This gives me the following:

[image: The result]

Then, I want to calculate the mean of the two best runs for each athlete for each of the BIB and COURSE but can't find an appropriate solution. I have tried to apply mean() like in the code below but that calculates the mean for each column in the dataframe and that's not what I want.

```
x = grupper.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(2, 'FINISH')).mean()
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need pass `mean` into `apply` method after `nsmallest`:

```
x = grupper['FINISH'].apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(2).mean())
```

In your solution should working also:

```
x = grupper.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(2, 'FINISH').mean())
```